# Selenium click not work

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Help me please.
Selenium does not click on element and element is clickable(selenium does not generate exception).
I try use Id, css, xpath locators, nothing did not help me.

**What should i do to decide my problem?**

Java code example.

```
WebElement sector = webDriver.findElement(By.id("sector-1"));
sector.click();
```

[image: At this page selenium does not click] 
After click system must open this page
[image]

[image: More detail html code]

Comment: could you try and use `WebElement sector = webDriver.findElements(By.id("sector-1:canvas"));       sector.get(0).click();` and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decide my problem.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sector-2:canvas\"]")));

    WebElement svgObject = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sector-2:canvas\"]"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver);
    builder.click(svgObject).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you try to interact with object inside a `<svg>` element. If so, you cannot manage it's child elements simply using `click()` method.

Try this instead:

```
WebElement svgObject = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//polygon[@id='sector-1:canvas']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.click(svgObject).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below XPath :

```
WebElement sector = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//g[@id='sector-1']/polygon"));
sector.click();
```

OR

```
WebElement sector = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//polygon[@id='sector-1:canvas']"));
sector.click();
```